# Cancel a replace all in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, search, replace

How do I cancel an ongoing "replace all" in Visual Studio 2010?

I'm currently working in a solution with a few thousand files, and I accidentally replaced "1" with "2" solution-wide instead of just across my cursor selection. I have TFS hooked up, so it's a hateful process to sit here for several minutes while every (nearly) file in my solution is checked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had no other changes, kill the devenv process and then revert all files after restart?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this. However, I didn't want to lose any changes that I'd made to the file I was working on prior to the replacement. I'll keep this in mind and remember to ctrl+s before I do a replace so that I can do this without worrying in the future.

Comment: If you know what file you were working in, and there is only one, save a copy of it, then revert all, restore the saved copy and finally then manually undo the replace all in just that file.